# Como consumir uma constante em outro componente JSX

Tags: javascript, html, react

Tenho uma constante:

```
const dados = [{
 id: 1,
 nome: 'Juliano',
 idade: 25,
 descricao: 'Front-end',
}, {
 id: 2,
 nome: 'Italo',
 idade: 29,
 descricao: 'Back-end',
}]
```

Exporto todo essa constante, via: export { dados }; Porém eu não sei como consumir ela em um componente separado, pois eu precisaria deixar da seguinte maneira:

```
<h1>{dados.nome}</h1>
<h2>{dados.idade}</h2>
<h3>{dados.descricao}</h3>
```

Porém não sei a sintaxe para consumi-lo depois de importado, com o:

```
import dados from './dados.jsx'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa fazer um destructuring:

```
import { dados } from './dados.jsx'
```

E se você quiser utilizar essa sintaxe:

```
<h1>{dados.nome}</h1>
<h2>{dados.idade}</h2>
<h3>{dados.descricao}</h3>
```

Deverá fazer um loop no array:

```
dados.map(dado) => {
  <h1>{dado.nome}</h1>
  <h2>{dado.idade}</h2>
  <h3>{dado.descricao}</h3>
}
```

Ou então acessar pelo índice no array:

```
<h1>{dados[0].nome}</h1>
<h2>{dados[0].idade}</h2>
<h3>{dados[0].descricao}</h3>
```

Mas assim só irá pegar o primeiro índice de seu array

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Perfeito muito obrigado Maycon; Deu tudo certo, estava esquecendo a sintaxe que é usada para consumi-lo.

Comment: Massa Juliano, fico feliz em poder ajudar